# NPM packages on WSL2 that require script to run have permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, wsl-2

My wsl2 (ubuntu 20.04) is set to use root user.

I can install any node package that does not require a script to run.  If it does require a script like the `node-sass` package then I get the error:

```
sh: 1: node: Permission denied
```

Same happens for npx commands like:

```
# npx npkill
/tmp/npx-a435a586.sh: 1: npkill: Permission denied
```

There are many threads here that state the fix is to set these values:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

But this does not change the behavior and the same error occurs. I have tried deleting node modules and also using the `--unsafe-perm` flag but it still has same error.  I have also tried restarting after changing node settings.

My versions:

- node: v16.13.2
- npm: 8.15.0
- wsl: Ubuntu-20.04

Anything else I can try?

Comment: *"set to use root user"* -- Via `/etc/wsl.conf` I assume (but want to confirm)?

Comment: That file doesn't exist.  I honestly don't remember how I set root as default user, I think it was a command in powershell

Comment: No worries - If you did it from PowerShell, perhaps something like `ubuntu.exe config --default-user root`?  If so, then that should ultimately have the same effect as the `/etc/wsl.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it doesn't seem helpful for me to say that it's working for me, but hopefully by walking through what I've done and comparing it to your installation we can spot a difference that might be causing the problem for you.

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 (distribution named "Ubuntu") on WSL2:

```bash
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

# Since you mention that you have set your user to be root:
sudo sh -c 'echo "[user]\ndefault=root" > /etc/wsl.conf'

wsl.exe -l -v
# Confirm your distribution name for the following command:
wsl.exe --terminate Ubuntu
```

Restart WSL, the user is now root:

```bash
# Use n version manager -- Just my personal preference:
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n -o n
bash n 16.13.2
npm install -g npm@8.15.0

npm install -g npkill
npx npkill
```

And it works as expected.

---

If you'd like to test it out on a "clean" distribution (without disturbing your existing one, that you can then compare), you can do the following.  First, in an Administrative PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\*' |
Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'install.tar.gz' } |
% { $_.FullName }
```

Copy the path for the distribution the clipboard for use later.  It should be something like:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2022.1.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\install.tar.gz
```

Back in a "Normal user" PowerShell session:

```bash
# Adjust paths/names as desired
mkdir $env:userprofile/WSL/instances/TestUbuntu
wsl --import TestUbuntu $env:userprofile/WSL/instances/TestUbuntu "<path_copied_above_in_quotes>" --version 2
wsl ~ -d TestUbuntu
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because the steps helped me get to the actual reason.  The project folder is mapped to docker so all files are owned by `www-data`.  Usually using root will trump www-data but for some reason this was the problem.  I set the project owner to root and then it worked.  A bit annoying as causes me some extra steps but it's working now